# Discord bot embedding custom emote js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot command that replies with an embed message the code looks like this. (yes im following a tutorial)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('**Library Wisp | SR - L Nightmare**')
        .setURL('https://sinoalice.game-db.tw/nightmares/ライブラリウィスプ')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/sANYH9P.png')
        .setColor('#E2B007')
        .addFields(
            { name: ':skillstory: **Blessed Armor (II)**', value: '\n SP:0 \n Prep. Time: 20s \n Duration 0s \n Effect: Greatly Increases Physial and Magical Defense for all surviving allies.'},
            { name: ':skillcolloseum: **Blessed Armor (II)**', value: '\n SP:0 \n Prep. Time: 60s \n Duration 0s \n Effect: Greatly Increases Physial and Magical Defense for all surviving front-allies.'},
            { name: '**Stats**', value: '**LEVEL** | lv 1 | lv 60 | lv 65 | lv 70 | lv 75 | lv 80 | \n **PATK** | 319 | 968 | 1023 | 1078 | 1133 | 1188 | \n **PDEF** | 323 | 972 | 1027 | 1082 | 1137 | 1192 |'},
        )

    message.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "lwisp",
    description: "",
    usage: "lwisp",
    accessableby: "Members",
    aliases: []
}
```

in within the fields I would like to have an emote displayed, I thought by using the emote comand the job would be done but I am wrong, it is a custom emote and what I am trying to achieve is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow !
In order to get your emotes on an embed you'll have to follow this few steps :

1. Go to your server where the emote is, type it in the chat box, like you would normally do to send it, and but a backslash (`\`) on front of it. After sending this, you should see something like this : `<:EmoteName:420150420046660911>`
2. Then, make sure that your bot is in the same server as where the emote is.
3. Now, if you copy-paste the full emote text you got earlier in one of your embed's fields, you should now be able to see your emotes inside of it !
4. (Optional) If your emote is animated, you'll have to add an `a` on front of your `:EmoteName:`, wiich would make the result look like this : `<a:EmoteName:420150420046660911>`

I hope that I was comprehensible enough, and that my explainations will help you to fix your issue ! :3

Comment: It seems that these emotes (using the notation shown above) work everywhere (in any server), even if the bot is not in the server, where the emote originates from. This method does still remain exclusive to bots, unless you have Discord Nitro.